# AppCode: Alamofire with Swift Async/Await: "request.serializingString().response" not available

Tags: swift, xcode, async-await, alamofire, appcode

I'm writing this because it caused me a few hours of work today. I figured it out so now maybe somebody else won't waste any time.

I'm an iOS developer and I use AppCode instead of Xcode.

I'm in the process of trying to update our app using Swift's new concurrency features. We use Alamofire for REST stuff.

**The problem:**

Trying to use Alamofire's concurrency methods **in AppCode** don't show up as valid methods. The IDE/Compiler didn't recognize the methods.

In my case, it was `.serializingString()`.

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire's Concurrency support requires Swift 5.6 as of Alamofire 5.6. If AppCode's compiler is behind it will report them as unavailable, as it can't see into the `swift(>=5.6.0)` block.

Comment: I saw that while I was trying to figure out what was wrong. Xcode compiler was running 5.6. I guess I didn’t even realize that AppCode could be running a different version.

Comment: so can I change it? or do i need to wait for AppCode update?

Answer (score 0):

Something about the Alamofire package isn't playing nice with AppCode.

It all works just fine. You can write the code in AppCode, even though the IDE won't appear to understand what you're doing.

I switched over to Xcode and everything looked nice. I ran it and it worked.